# loop R multiple samples from single dataset

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, stata

I am attempting to create a simple loop in R, where I have a large dataset and I want to create multiple smaller samples from this dataset and export them to excel:

I thought it would work like this, but it doesn't:

```
 idorg <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
 x <- c(14,20,21,16,17)
 y <- c(31,21,20,50,13)
 dataset <- cbind (idorg,x,y)


 for (i in 1:4)
 {
 attempt[i] <- dataset[sample(1:nrow(dataset), 3, replace=FALSE),]
 write.table(attempt[i], "C:/Users/me/Desktop/WWD/Excel/dataset[i].xls", sep='\t')
 }
```

In Stata you would need to preserve and restore your data when doing a loop like this, but is this also necessary in R?

Comment: Why is this being voted to close? IMO this is a perfectly suitable Q for this site.

Answer (score 5):

You have following problems:

1. attempt is not declared, so `attempt[i]` cannot be assigned to. Either make it a matrix to fill up within the loop (if you want to keep the samples), or use it as a temporary variable `attempt`.
2. The file name is take literary, you need to use `paste()` or `sprintf()` to include the value of the variable `i` in the file name.

Here is a working version of the code:

```
idorg <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
x <- c(14,20,21,16,17)
y <- c(31,21,20,50,13)
dataset <- cbind (idorg,x,y)

for (i in 1:4)  {
  attempt <- dataset[sample(1:nrow(dataset), 3, replace=FALSE),]
  write.table(attempt, sprintf( "C:/Users/me/Desktop/WWD/Excel/dataset[%d].xls", i ), sep='\t')
}
```

Will Excel be able to read such a tab-separated table? I'm not sure; I would make a comma separated table and save it as `.csv`.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Stata, you don't need to preserve and restore your data for this kind of operation in R.

I think January's solution solves your problem, but I wanted to share another alternative: using `lapply()` to get a list of all the samples of the dataset:

```
set.seed(1) # So you can reproduce these results
temp <- setNames(lapply(1:4,
                        function(x) { 
                          x <- dataset[sample(1:nrow(dataset),
                                              3, replace = FALSE), ]; x }),
                 paste0("attempt.", 1:4))
```

This has created a `list()` named "temp" that comprises four `data.frame`s.

```
temp
# $attempt.1
#      idorg  x  y
# [1,]     2 20 21
# [2,]     5 17 13
# [3,]     4 16 50
# 
# $attempt.2
#      idorg  x  y
# [1,]     5 17 13
# [2,]     1 14 31
# [3,]     3 21 20
# 
# $attempt.3
#      idorg  x  y
# [1,]     5 17 13
# [2,]     3 21 20
# [3,]     2 20 21
# 
# $attempt.4
#      idorg  x  y
# [1,]     1 14 31
# [2,]     5 17 13 
# [3,]     4 16 50
```

Lists are very convenient in R. You can now use `lapply()` to do other fun things, like if you wanted to find out the row sums, you can do `lapply(temp, rowSums)`. Or, if you wanted to output separate CSV files (readable by Excel), you can do something like this:

```
lapply(names(temp), function(x) write.csv(temp[[x]],
                             file = paste0(x, ".csv")))
```